# ALGLIB library, rbfmodel and failing syntax for real_2d_array data type

Tags: c++, graphics, syntax, static-libraries, interpolation

I have matrix of 3x[large number] values I would like to interpolate using polynomials. Looking through the net I stumbled across a PSU [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=F7B8D9FE1E17878518279DB4BB405988?doi=10.1.1.35.2949&rep=rep1&type=pdf) about several kinds of algorithms  to fit multivariate data. I looked up the firs one, and now I have successfully installed the static library ALGLIB on my system.

The problem: [here](http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#example_rbf_d_qnn) is one example using the algorithm I want to use. It is simple and straight forward. The problem I have relates to the "real_2d_array xy", in the example you will see this is set to a string as follows

```
real_2d_array xy = "[[-1,0,2],[+1,0,3]]";
```

when I compile this, along with the rest of the example, it finishes well and runs with no problem given the desired output. HOWEVER, my data set is large >30,000 points per graph and I created a string to store all this points in the above format as follows;

```
    //definitions, functions and housekeeping

    xyz_data+="[";                   //First bracket.
    std::stringstream ss;            //Used to convert numbers to string

    // other code with loops and more house keeping

    //This part repeats for every point in my data set
    xyz_data+="[";
    ss<<lenght;
    xyz_data+=ss.str()+",";
    ss.str("");
    ss<<rval;
    xyz_data+=ss.str()+",";
    ss.str("");
    ss<<temp.size();
    xyz_data+=ss.str()+"],";

    //more unrelated stuff

    xyz_data.erase(xyz_data.size()-1);  //Delete the extra comma for the last data pointas a result of the loop above.

    xyz_data+="]";   //closing data to fit format in example from ALGLIB

    //Declaring data type for matrix, from the ALGLIB
    real_2d_array xyz;
    xyz=xyz_data;       //Because in the example the RHS is a string, I assumed this would work, but it does not. I get an error about data types.

    //Running interpolation
    double v;
    rbfmodel model;
    rbfcreate(2, 1, model);
    rbfsetpoints(model, xyz);
    rbfreport rep;
    rbfsetalgoqnn(model);
    rbfbuildmodel(model, rep);
    printf("%d\n", int(rep.terminationtype));
    v = rbfcalc2(model, 0.0, 0.0);
    printf("%.2f\n", double(v));
```

ERROR MESSAGE:  error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'alglib::real_2d_array' and 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}'),

Could someone please explain to how to make this work? I am missing something subtle, or so it seems, about being able to use strings directly but not as variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what's happening. It turns out the real_2d_array will not take a string, but it will  take characters, or in my case an array of characters. That's it.

My implementation is

```
    xyz_data.replace(xyz_data.size()-1,1,"]");       //Delete the extra comma as a result of the loop above.
    char *DATA=new char[xyz_data.size()];            //Declare pointer to my array and allocate memory.
    memcpy(DATA,xyz_data.c_str(),xyz_data.size()+1);   //Copy data from string to character.
    real_2d_array xyz(DATA);                           //Accepted like VISA. Works like a charm.
```